# Accessing properties x and y of CCSprite from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

If I have a sprite in a NSMutableArray of sprites in Cocos2d and need to access the x and y values of a specific sprite how can I do that?

```
[array objectAtIndex:0].position.y // or .x for x value
```

doesn't work when trying to access the element of y from a specific sprite in the array. But, I can not think of any other way to get either the x or y value of a CCSprite. How can I get the x and y values of NSMutableArray containing CCSprites?

(And I can't find any getX or getY methods either in the doc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the value returned by `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` so the compiler knows it’s a `CCSprite *` object:

```
((CCSprite *)[array objectAtIndex:0]).position.y;
```

Alternatively, you could store the return value in a `CCSprite *` variable:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then use this variable to obtain the corresponding position:

```
sprite.position.y
```